# add custom wordpress attribute for generate thumbnail in xml feed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to create an XML product feed for some external services
so I using `WordPress plugin` to generate that feed.

the problem is that the plugin using the main image for the feed.
so I want to add the custom attribute to change that main product image to thumbnail product image

the plugin and `woocommerce` doesn't have thumbnail attribute by default

I'm using [WooCommerce Product Feed Plugin PRO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-product-feed-pro/) WordPress plugin

[image]

Comment: I really can't understand how we can help you without knowing what plugin you are using to generate the xml feed.

Comment: @jnhghy-AlexandruJantea https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-product-feed-pro/

Comment: So what have you tried so far?